# Названия шнурка для обвязки тортов

Tags: названия

Подскажите, как назвать эту проволоку, шнур, шнурок, связывающий торты, коробки из-под пицц?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вижу, то техническое название "Шпагат полипропиленовый": [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше (когда трава была зеленее) торты обвязывали натуральным (хлопчатобумажным) шпагатом, он коричневый такой. Картинку уж не буду добавлять.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы употребил слово "тесёмка".